# Quick sort not working

Tags: java

while running above code the first pivot is returned as 3.This pivot is transmitted as 2 in first recursion method but in second recursion it does not take value 4. can some one identify what is problem.

```
  class QuickSortRevision{

   int pivot;

   void QuickSort(int[] arr,int low,int high){

        if(low>=high)
        return;

        pivot = quickSortPivot(arr,low,high);//first execution pivot =3

        QuickSort(arr,low,pivot-1);//this is taking 0,2 as parameter;

        QuickSort(arr,pivot+1,high);//but this is not taking 4,8 as parameter;

   }
   int quickSortPivot(int[] arr,int low,int high){

           int temp,index,partition,lindex,hindex;
           lindex=low;
           hindex=high-1;
           partition = arr[high];
           index=high;
           System.out.println("low : "+low+" high "+high);

           while(lindex!=hindex){

               while(arr[lindex]<partition  && (lindex!=hindex) ){
                 lindex++;
               }   

               while(arr[hindex]>partition && (lindex!=hindex) ){
                 hindex--;
               }
                  if( lindex!=hindex)
                  {

                     temp=arr[lindex];
                     arr[lindex]=arr[hindex];
                     arr[hindex]=temp;
                     lindex++;hindex--;
                 }
           }  
           temp=arr[lindex];
           arr[lindex]=partition;
           arr[index]=temp;

      System.out.println("lindex:  "+lindex);
       return lindex; 
   }

void printArray(int[] arr)
{
  for(int element  : arr)
  System.out.print(" "+element);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

   QuickSortRevision qs = new QuickSortRevision();
   int arr[]={17,41,5,22,54,6,29,3,13};
   qs.QuickSort(arr,0,arr.length-1);
   qs.printArray(arr);

}}
```

Comment: You should provide details about your error or what goes wrong, exactly

Comment: Where is the `Stack`Trace in `Stack`Overflow ?

Comment: The problem is with pivot who is declared as class variable rather than function variable, and so recursion is unable to retain value. But what is the difference? even if we declare pivot as function variable it will still get  modified

Comment: No it will not be modified. Each time the function is called, a new int will be allocated in memory. This int is local to this function call, meaning that if you call your function recursively it will use its own version of pivot, leaving your pivot unmodified when it returns.

Comment: Thanks  StephaneM. Really appreciate your fast reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call QuickSort the class member `pivot`is assigned the value 3. Then a recursive call to QuickSort invokes quickSortPivot whose result is assigned to `pivot` (and further recursive calls also modify this value). When this call to Quicksort returns, the value of `pivot`has been modified!

You shoud declre `pivot` as a variable of the method `QuickSort`, not an instance variable of the class `QuickSortRevision`

PS: the function `QuickSort` should be called `quickSort`

Comment: Yes that solved the problem.But i still don't understand why pivot should be necessarily declare inside QuickSort function and not outside. even if we declare pivot as function variable it will still get modified isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

replace you code `lindex!=hindex` to `lindex<=hindex`.
because there a sence like `lindex > hindex`.
The code like this:

```
   public class QuickSortRevision{

   int pivot;

   static int id = 1;

   void QuickSort(int[] arr,int low,int high){

        if(low>=high)
        return;

        pivot = quickSortPivot(arr,low,high);//first execution pivot =3

        QuickSort(arr,low,pivot-1);//this is taking 0,2 as parameter;

        QuickSort(arr,pivot+1,high);//but this is not taking 4,8 as parameter;

   }


   int quickSortPivot(int[] arr,int low,int high){

           int temp,index,partition,lindex,hindex;
           lindex=low;
           hindex=high - 1;
           partition = arr[high];
           index=high;


           while(lindex <= hindex){


               while(arr[lindex]<partition  && (lindex<=hindex) ){
                 lindex++;
               }   
               while(arr[hindex]>partition && (lindex<=hindex) ){
                     hindex--;
               }
               System.out.println("low : "+low+" high "+high);
              if( lindex<=hindex)
              {

                 temp=arr[lindex];
                 arr[lindex]=arr[hindex];
                 arr[hindex]=temp;
                 lindex++;hindex--;
             }






           }  
           temp=arr[lindex];
           arr[lindex]=partition;
           arr[index]=temp;

           // System.out.println(lindex+" "+arr[lindex]);
           System.out.println("lindex:  "+lindex);
       return lindex; 
   }

void printArray(int[] arr)
{
  for(int element  : arr)
  System.out.print(" "+element);
}




public static void main(String[] args){

   QuickSortRevision qs = new QuickSortRevision();
   int arr[]={17,41,5,22,54,6,29,3,13};
   qs.QuickSort(arr,0,arr.length-1);
   qs.printArray(arr);

}
```

}